# How to redirect index.php but exclude index.php?route=

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I like to redirect urls that include **index.php** or **index.php/** but exclude urls that include **index.php?route=** the code below redirect index/php and index.php/ but how to exclude index.php?route= ?

i tried to add exclude conditions like this one but is not working

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^index.php?route=
```

Full code

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^index.php?route=
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index.php|index.php$ $1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?index\.php/(.*) /$1$2? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: The test string pattern in your `THE_REQUEST` is wrong it should be `!/index\.php\?route=` without the leading `^`

Comment: @AmitVerma still same problem

Comment: Try clearing your browser caches.